# Comparing time stamps with php?

Tags: php

Are there any built in functions that do unix time stamp comparisons in php?

EDIT: I mean timestamps of the form "2001-12-20 00:00:01". Also edited title... my apologies as this isn't a unix timestamp

Comment: it's a number, dude. it's just a number. PHP has built in functions to compare numbers for sure

Comment: My timestamps are actually date/time like "2001-12-20 00:00:01"

Comment: "2001-12-20 00:00:01" isn't a timestamp, it's a string. Convert your string values to integer values using using strtotime() or to DateTime objects, then do the comparison.

Comment: it's not a unix timestamp then. it's mysql timestamp. Still you can compare it just using `>, <, ==` as well. Such a date format lets you compare these dates as strings.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use >, <, = these are integers you do not need any specific functions to compare them.

Comment: Yup, nothing more to say about it. By the way, this works for PHP 5's new `DateTime` objects as well.

Comment: My timestamps are of the form "2001-12-20 00:00:01"

Comment: Make your fields DATETIME then and again comapre with >,< and =

Answer (score 2):

A Unix Timestamp is just an integer. What do you want to compare?

Answer (score 2):

If the timestamp you want to compare is in string format (e.g., maybe it was sent as a parameter, etc. to your PHP script) then you can convert it to a number using PHP's [strtotime()][1] function.

You an then compare easily using `<` and `>`, etc.